# Ruby PORO class fails with build method

Tags: ruby

I'm very surprised where my class what looks like

```
class MyBuilder
  def self.build
    return 'my build method is work'
  end
end
```

on production(ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]):

```
1.9.3-p551 :003 > OrderItemBuilder.build
=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

local(ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]):

```
[3] pry(main)> OrderItemBuilder.build
=> "my build method is work"
```

I can't to understand what code call my method on production.

Comment: Is it a rails application, If not what do you mean by Production?

Comment: It might help if you post how `OrderItemBuilder` is related to `MyBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading a different set of gems in production vs development? If yes, maybe one of them is adding a `.build` method. Here's a way to find out who added the method to the class:

```
OrderItemBuilder.method(:build).owner
```

Here's an example from a Rails app:

```
User.method(:create).owner
#=> ActiveRecord::Persistence::ClassMethods
```

Comment: Theory is good, but:

    OrderItemBuilder.method(:build).owner
    => #<Class:OrderItemBuilder>

Comment: Are there any other methods to get known about method content?
like as 'show-source'

Comment: Well, you can just hold on to the method object you get and explore it further. `build = OrderItemBuilder.method(:build)`, then stuff like `build.source_location`, `build.arity` etc.

Comment: And since you're using Pry: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Source-browsing